# My Prim's algorithm does not generate maze properly

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, graph-theory, maze

I am trying to implement a randomly generated maze using Prim's algorithm. But the program does not generate a maze properly. Please take a look and give me some advice

Here is my picture of a maze:

[image]

The maze should be look like this: 
[image]
Prim's algorithm:

```
private void Prims(){
            List<Vertex> res = new ArrayList<>();
            PriorityQueue<Vertex> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(CostComparator.compare_W());
            for (int i = 0; i < grids.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < grids[i].length; j++){
                    priorityQueue.offer(grids[i][j]);
                }
            }
            grids[0][0].setG(0);
            while(!priorityQueue.isEmpty()){
                Vertex current = priorityQueue.poll();
                if(current.getPrevious() != null){
                    res.add(current);
                }
                for(Edge edge: current.getEdges()){
                    Vertex destination = edge.getDestination();
                    if(priorityQueue.contains(destination) && destination.getG() > edge.getWeight()){
                        destination.setPrevious(current);
                        destination.setG(edge.getWeight());
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++){
                if(i % 2 == 0){
                    res.get(i).setStyle(3);
                }
            }
            update(5);
        }
```

Vertex class:

```
public class Vertex {
    private int x, y, style;
    private int f, h, g;
    private Vertex previous;
    private List<Edge> edges;
    private boolean isVisited;
}
```

Edge class:

```
public class Edge {
    private int weight;
    private Vertex destination;
    private Vertex start;
}
```

I also read this article [Implementing a randomly generated maze using Prim's Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739751/implementing-a-randomly-generated-maze-using-prims-algorithm), but I haven't still be able to solve my problem. I saw @Hoopje in that post said that if both coordinate are even, then this cell must be a passage. otherwise, it is the wall. However, when I drew it out, it is not correct because it seems like a Chess board. Thank you.

Comment: *"But the result is not correct."* Please edit the question to explain what specifically about the result is not correct.

Comment: @kaya3 Hi. After running the program, the maze seems like not correct as the included image. Is there any mistake in my Prim's algorithm?

Comment: What, specifically, about the included image is not correct? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kaya3 I have tried to edit my question and also attached a proper maze image. My question is my program does not generate a maze properly. Sorry for a bad description.

Comment: Please make your code [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Java's `PriorityQueue<T>` does not update its internal state automatically when you change the weight of your vertices during relaxation. The solution to this is to [remove and re-insert the vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1871303/7506861) whenever you change its weight.

This may not be the only issue, but it is the one most apparent to me from just looking at your code.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for letting me know this. Is there anything wrong with my algorithm

Comment: @newbie if this answer did solve your problem you can accept it - if you have follow up question feel free to ask another one!